# Is it wrong to enforce NOT NULL using application code?

Tags: php, mysql

I have about 6 tables in my MySQL database, like

```
mysql> describe Quiz;
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| quiz_id      | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name         | varchar(25) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| category     | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| is_published | tinyint(1)  | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| open_count   | int(11)     | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| finish_count | int(11)     | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

In all 6 tables, while writing `CREATE TABLE ...` i didn't enforce `NOT NULL` on each attribute(as visible above), but they should be NOT NULL.

Rows will be inserted in these tables using my PHP code. So I can ensure that none of them is NULL, before inserting.

I wanted to know, if there is a possible flaw in **enforcing NOT NULL using application code, rather than MySQL?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Off the top of my head, I can give you two reasons to enforce it in the database *in addition to doing it in code*.

- If a bug shows up in your PHP code, your data won't be corrupt. You'll notice the bug right away if you just check your return codes from the database.
- If someone decides to update data manually in the database, they won't be able to mistakenly leave fields as NULL that your application code can't cope with.

Comment: Thanks, I would rather not want a human to break my database. ;)

Answer (score 3):

The best course of action will be to enforce constraints in both database and application. Having the constraints in the database is essential since the DB can be accessed by other application or even updated manually (let's say from the workbentch if we are talking about MySQL).

On the other hand, a proper front end application should always check the values of the form that are intended to go in the database.

In your case adding the constraints to the database fields should be easy by using ALTER statements in your tables.

I hope that this can help you decide.

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessarily a "flaw" in that it can work, but the MySQL query optimizer treats columns differently if they're defined as `NOT NULL` for certain storage engines.

It's also more of a hassle to write your own code to enforce it.

Why not just run an `ALTER` on your table to make them `NOT NULL`?

Comment: +1 Thanks, but is there a single-statement to do this, or do I have to 'ALTER TABLE ...' a dozen times? ;)

Comment: You'll have to do one alter per table. Each alter can touch multiple columns, but only within a single table.

Answer (score 1):

You should enforce it in both.

Applications have bugs - and you do never want them to danger the integrity of your database. Setting proper column specifications is where preventing this happens.

Answer (score 1):

As a general principle it's better to use constraints such as not null at the database level. This means that any other application that may use the database in future (or version 2 of your app) does not have to include this data integritity logic if it is not required.

Leave data integrity to the database and application logic to the application

Answer (score 1):

Enforcing the constraint at the database level sounds correct. But personally I do not follow this practice and enforce this integrity at code level:

- The constraints often change, specially during early phases of development
- I try to limit the number of locations where a change needs to be made if the constraint needs to be revised
- There are certain constraints you cannot do in database -- like enforcing an email address in an email address field, an alhpa-numeric-only username, etc -- I treat them as another form of constraint and implement them in code. Likewise for null/not null

Comment: +1 thanks, I am used to doing all of the checks in PHP, but duplication in checks is good. (lol, in fact triplication first JavaScript, then PHP, then MySQl)